# Angular NGRX Effects nothing happening

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm using ngrx Effects to make a http call to my server. But the effect is not getting invoked. I want to make the http call when the component loads. So I do a store.dispatch in ngOnInit, but nothing happens.

users.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromUsersReducer from './states/users.reducer';
import * as UsersActions from './states/users.action';
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private store: Store<fromUsersReducer.State>,
  ) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new UsersActions.Load());
  }
}
```

users.actions.ts

```
export enum UsersActionTypes {
  Load = '[Users] Load',
  LoadSuccess = '[Users] Load Success',
  LoadFail = '[Users] Load Fail',
}    
export class Load implements Action {
  readonly type = UsersActionTypes.Load;
}    
export class LoadSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = UsersActionTypes.LoadSuccess;    
  constructor(public payload: Users[]) {}
}    
export class LoadFail implements Action {
  readonly type = UsersActionTypes.LoadFail;    
  constructor(public payload: string) {}
}    
export type UsersActions = Load | LoadSuccess | LoadFail;
```

users.effects.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersEffects {
  constructor(private action$: Actions, private usersService: UsersService) {}

  @Effect()
  loadUsersDetails$ = this.action$.pipe(
    ofType(UsersAction.UsersActionTypes.Load),
    mergeMap((action: UsersAction.Load) =>
      this.usersService.getUsers().pipe(
        map(response => {
          if (response) {
            let users = new Array<Users>();
            console.log(response);
            .........
            return new UsersAction.LoadSuccess(users);
          }
        }),
        catchError(err => of(new UsersAction.LoadFail(err)))
      )
    )
  );
}
```

users.reducer.ts

```
export interface State extends fromRoot.State {
  users: UsersState;
}
export interface UsersState {
  users: Users[];
}
const getUsersFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<UsersState>('users');
export const getUsersDetails = createSelector(
  getUsersFeatureState,
  state => state.users
);
export const initialState: UsersState = {
  users: [],
};
export function reducer(state = initialState, action: UsersActions) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UsersActionTypes.LoadSuccess:
      console.log('Users Reducer - Received Full Data for Users: ', action.payload);
      return {
        ...state,
        users: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

users.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [UsersComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    MaterialModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature('users', reducer),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([UsersEffects])
  ],
  exports: [UsersComponent],
  providers: [UsersService],
  entryComponents: [UsersComponent]
})
export class UsersModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot({}),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
  ],
  ............
})
export class AppModule {}
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: A bit of a guess: should this `EffectsModule.forRoot([UsersEffects])` be `EffectsModule.forFeature([UsersEffects])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one `EffectsModule.forRoot`, try:

```
  EffectsModule.forFeature([UsersEffects])
```